# Maintain quality while zooming UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am using UIImage inside a ScrollView to zoom an image. But zooming reduces the quality of the image. My original image dimensions are 1200x1600 pixel and UIImage rect are 1024x768 pixel. How can I maintain the quality of the image in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any zoom scale beyond 1.0x reduces the image quality. If you want absolutely no degrade in quality you should set the `maximumZoomScale` property of your scroll view to 1.0.

In your case, that means you can zoom your image from 576x768 (aspect fit of your scroll view) to 1200x1600 (its original size), approximately 2x.